# Using .each() for targeting each child differently in Jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="Parent">
    <div id="child-1" class="post-1">
        <header class="aheader">
           <div class="target">
               <a href="http://example.com/author/user1/">user1</a>
           </div> 
        </header>
    </div>
    <div id="child-2" class="post-2">
        <header class="aheader">
           <div class="target">
               <a href="http://example.com/author/user2/">user1</a>
           </div> 
        </header>
    </div>
    <div id="child-3" class="post-3">
        <header class="aheader">
           <div class="target">
               <a href="http://example.com/author/user2/">user1</a>
           </div> 
        </header>
    </div>
    <div id="child-4" class="post-4">
        <header class="aheader">
           <div class="target">
               <a href="http://example.com/author/user3/">user1</a>
           </div> 
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Requirement:
1) I want to target each of the class="target" through an iteration so as the change the href to remove author from the href such that the respetive hrefs are:

```
http://example.com/user1
http://example.com/user2and so on
```

This is what I have tried in Jquery:

```
$(".parent > div").each(function() {
var authorlink = $("div > header > target  > a").attr("href").substring(0,19) + $(""div > header > target  > a"").attr("href").substring(26);
$("div > header > target  > a").attr("href", authorlink);
});
```

The (undesired) result:
All the target elements are assigned href of:http://example.com/

What is apparently happening:

```
First iteration: all elements are getting assigned http://example.com/user1 and so following this
Second iteration: all elements are getting assigned http://example.com/
Third iteration: all elements are getting assigned http://example.com/
Fourth iteration: all elements are getting assigned http://example.com/
```

Limitations:
1) I cannot change this php generated structure (wordpress)
2) div id= child-1, div id= child-2,etc are dynamically added by user intervention

Help:
1) What am I doing wrong?
2) Is .each() the right function to use?
3) Detailed help would be much appreciated as I am just a novice.

Comment: You do realize that you have syntax errors, and that classnames are case sensitive ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
$('div[class^="post"]').find('a').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace(/\/author/, ''));
});
```

### Why your solution isn't working as expected

One of the main things I notice is inside of your each loop. You are simply referencing $("div > header > target  > a") which will give you an array of all the divs on the page that match that definition.

If you really wanted to do that you should use that as your main loop element:

```
$("div > header > target  > a").each(function(){
```

Then reference the matched element during it's iteration using `$(this)`

```
var authorlink = $(this);
//etc...
```

You really over complicated something rather simple and it seems to be due to your misunderstanding of how jQuery interacts with the DOM. I suggest you dig through jquery selector docs until your eyes bleed. it will be a good resource for you: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

The code I provided at the top is streamlined version of what you were attempting made a bit simpler by the use of a regular expression, that way we only replace content that matches exactly what we want to replace, no guessing based on substrings.

You should read more about RegExp too: http://www.regexr.com/

Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: thanks Eric....works just the way I want it. Like I said, I am just a novice playing around Jquery...will definitely look into the suggested links

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div[class="target"] a').each(function(){
alert($(this).prop('href').replace('/author', ''));
});
```